# Migrating password auth from ASP to PHP

Tags: php, asp.net, drupal

I am having a few issues migrating the user accounts of a ASP site to Drupal.

The ASP site creates a password hash by HashEncode(Password+Salt)

I am trying to figure out which is an equivalent function in php so I can match it in our drupal password module.

Someone did a decent attempt at http://forums.overclockers.com.au/showthread.php?t=632736&page=2 but it doesnt work.

I heard that HashEncode is sha1 but I dont think this is the case. On another site it shows that the two dont output the same and I have confirmed the php part on my local.

```
HashEncode("ABCD") = A11D4F0A70B882D58494B188DA0430CF4F17CFA8

sha1('ABCD') = fb2f85c88567f3c8ce9b799c7c54642d0c7b41f6
```

Does anyone know how ASP HashEncode works and how I can reproduce it in php so that I can migrate across the users?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score -1, accepted):

As already mentioned on the forum you've linked, try to find the source code of the HashEncode function to see what exactly is happening there. *Maybe ASP is using [SHA2](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SHA-2), which can has multiple key-length (e.g. SHA256/SHA512).*

**But** you can **also** delete all passwords, so your users need to recreate them on the new software. This way, all passwords will be generated using PHP's functions.

Example using SHA256 + salt:

```
/**
 * generate salted password
 * @param string $plainTextPassword
 * @param string $salt default = NULL (create new salt)
 * @param int $saltLength default = 9
 * @return string password-hash
 */
function passwordHash($plainTextPassword, $salt = null, $saltLength = 9)
{
    if(is_null($salt))
    {
        // create new salt
        $salt = substr(sha1(uniqid(mt_rand(), true)), 0, $saltLength);
    }
    else
    {
        $salt = substr($salt, 0, $saltLength);
    }
    return $salt . hash('sha256', $salt . $plainTextPassword);
}
```

Comment: I am developing on mac and don't have ASP so I cannot easily look into the source code. cheers

Answer (score 0):

It's usually a HMACSHA1 hash, but the trick is to make sure that its utf16 encoded.  Below is a javascript implementation.

```
function str2rstr_utf16le(input) {
  var output = [],
      i = 0,
      l = input.length;

  for (; l > i; ++i) {
    output[i] = String.fromCharCode(
      input.charCodeAt(i)        & 0xFF,
      (input.charCodeAt(i) >>> 8) & 0xFF
    );
  }

  return output.join('');
}

//utf 16 encoding is important
var pwd = str2rstr_utf16le("test");
var hash = CryptoJS.HmacSHA1(pwd, pwd);

var encodedPassword = CryptoJS.enc.Base64.stringify(hash);
alert(encodedPassword);
```